# if $a = 0 \mod p $ and $a \not = 0 \mod p ^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let $a = bc$ if $a = 0 \mod p $ and $a \not = 0 \mod p ^2$ with $p$ prime. what can we deduce? ($a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$)

I have that if $a = 0 \mod p$ then either $b = 0 \mod p$ or $c = 0 \mod p$ (can both be equal to $0 \mod p$?), without loss of generality, assume $b = 0 \mod p$ then we have that $a \not = 0 \mod p^2$ what can we deduce about $c$? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p^2 \nmid a \Rightarrow p^2 \nmid bc$.

But it holds that $b \equiv 0 \mod p$, so it cannot hold that $c \equiv 0 \mod{p}$.

Otherwise $p \mid b$ and $p \mid c$, so $p^2 \mid bc \Rightarrow p^2 \mid a$, that is a contradiction.

Comment: I said $a_0 \not = 0 \mod p^2$ not $p$ I think you misread edit: it seems as though I wrote $a_0 \not= 0 \mod p$ once also - will edit.

Comment: I edited my answer. @paperclip22

Comment: many thanks that helped

Comment: @paperclip22 You are welcome :)